# Can I create (and write) file from MySql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to log some data when my MySql tables are updated, and I need to write it into a log file (.csv probably).

Is there any way to do this?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you using mysql? from command line, php, some other language maybe?

Comment: well, I have a java app, but the request was to do this from trigger (clients don't want to change code). I manage to do that, but it can't be done directly. here is my workflow: 1) trigger writes into some temp table, then every hour, cron job write logs into file, delete all logs, and that's it...

Comment: you can write it to file, but only once (cant append to existing file). also, you can't create new file for every entry with new name, and merge it, because you cant create dynamic file names from trigger...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) statement with INTO OUTFILE option, it will help you to output information to CSV-file.